# Python - Pandas - Graph vs dict? (Networkx)

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I am new to world of python-grpahs. I have data in a pandas dataframe in format given below. Source column contains values which feed into Target column. So I need to build a graph or dicts which gives me a list [C,B,A] when I ask for values 'D' feeds to. I was looking at options Networkx provides to handle pandas dataframe. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

```
df = 
    Target Source
    A       B
    B       C
    C       D
```

Comment: Are you looking for constant length of list? Is it always 3 elements in the past (C, B, A)?

Comment: It is not fixed length. It can vary. Eg: If I am searching for 'C' I will have only [B,A]. If I search for 'B', I get [A]. So the length can vary based on the value I am looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I get that at the beginning there may not be enough items to create 3 elements list. But after that should they always be 3 most recent (if available) elements from Column1 or could it be 5 or 50?

Comment: It can be anything. It is not fixed to X most recent. It needs to traverse and get all the dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I found a way to do it using networkx library. I will build a graph using below code "G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df_pt_data, 'source', 'target', create_using=nx.DiGraph())". Then I can print its dependencies by doing this "nx.descendants(G, 'D'))"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to do it using networkx library. I will build a graph using below code "G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df_pt_data, 'source', 'target', create_using=nx.DiGraph())". Then I can print its dependencies by doing this "nx.descendants(G, 'D'))"